# How to keep your friends in Facebook from seeing specific friends on friends list

Tags: facebook

Is there a way on Facebook to keep friends on my friends list from seeing a specific friend on my same friends list?

Answer (score 2):

Not to such a granular level that John can't see Jane on your friends list. You can, however, block John from seeing who you are friends with at all.

From your profile, click over to the **Friends** tab and select **Edit Privacy** from the flyout menu.

[image: step 1]

Change your friends list privacy to **Custom**

[image: step 2]

Add in an exclusion for any users you wish to block. You can also enter in entire friends lists (custom lists you've created or smart lists automatically created by Facebook).

[image: step 3]